# how to Convert Lambda expression to Func<> variable

Tags: c#, variables, lambda, func

I have code for searching file. And now have Lambda Expression for filtering that.How to convert the Expression to `Func<string>` variable.
Thanks

Code :

```
Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*" + KeyWord + "*").Where(f => formatFile.Contains(f.Split('.').Last().ToLower()));
```

into variable :

```
Func<string> Lambda = ?? (f => formatFile.Contains(f.Split('.').Last().ToLower())) \\ convert the Expression;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be as easy as:

```
Func<string,bool> lambda = f => formatFile.Contains(f.Split('.').Last().ToLower());
```

The bool seems to be the part you were missing (this expression takes a string and returns a bool).

Comment: Thanks :). It Works. I just found out, it must use `bool`.